# CSS on CDN loaded after web page has finished loading

Tags: css, asynchronous, synchronization, html, cdn

I have a webpage using CDN to stream CSS files. The situation I ran into was : My webpage load too fast that when it finished loading, the CSS files (on CDN) are still loading. So that you can see a flash screen with you webpage WITHOUT any styles (cause the css on cdn is not loaded yet). So how can I keep them load synchronously, to prevent that "flash screen". Thanks :)

Comment: @Musa : I'm just wondering are there any way to make them loading in order, it's not a matter of the speed of CDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If caching is configured properly, this would not be an issue - only witnessed by the end user once upon the initial load.

If your site has a dedicated "first visit" landing page (welcome/login/disclaimer etc.), you could include the base styles inline (i.e. only the subset of rules the page immediately relies on) and lazy-load the CSS from your CDN in the background.

That being said, @Musa is absolutely correct: if this is an issue, *get a better CDN*